# Trouble Understanding the output of this java code

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr = {2, 1, -7, 16, -2, 11};

    for (int i = 5; i >= 1;  i--){         
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 2*arr[i – 1];
    }
}
```

The results from this code is equal to : `{2, 5, -5, 2, 30, 7}` I'm just confused on how the formula actually works to produce these results. The code starts from position 5 and checks each number in the array backwards, but what is the actual math behind this? I tried substituting 5 into i, but the results I get are different when I try to work it out myself in my head. Anybody able to help me here?

Comment: do you understand how array works?

Comment: Learn the basic from book , before posting on **stackoverflow** .

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see what each line of code does.

Answer (score 1):

Given Array = {2, 1, -7, 16, -2, 11};

Iteration of your code :

```
i=5:
array[5] = array[5] + 2*array[4]
array[5] = 11 + (2*-2)
array[5] = 11 - 4 = 7

i=4:
array[4] = array[4] + 2*array[3]
array[4] = -2 + 32 = 30
```

similarly all others follow

I understand that you are a beginner. By the way this is Java not Javascript. Both are different. I recommend you to study about arrays or use debugger in your IDE so that you can see how the code is working.